# How to prove this equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, fourier-transform

In J.J. Sakurai's Modern QM(Third edition), section 6.4.1, the author says that the equation 6.104
$$
\frac{e^{i\bf{k\cdot x}}}{(2π)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{1}{(2π)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sum_l(2l+1)i^lj_l(kr)P_l(\hat{\bf{k}}\cdot\hat{\bf{r}}),
$$

where $j_l$ is the spherical Bessel funtion of order $l$ and $\hat{\bf{r}}$ represents the unit vector in $\bf{x}$ direction, can be proved by using the following integral representation for $j_l(kr)$:
$$
j_l(kr)=\frac{1}{2i^l}\int_{-1}^1e^{ikr\cos{θ}}P_l(\cos{θ})d(\cos{θ}).
$$
I don't understand how one can use this representation to prove 6.104. Could someone write about the details please?

Comment: There is a conceptual way to understand this. Legendre polynomials $\{P_l(x)\}$ serve as an orthogonal basis over $[-1,1]$. Therefore, for any variable defined on $[-1,1]$ (in this case the variable is $\hat{k} \cdot \hat{r}$), the function can be expressed in terms of the basis of Legendre polynomials, and the expression can be derived through dot product, which is integral in this sense. This is similar to what we do for Fourier series.

Comment: It is a good way to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the completeness property of the Legendre polynomials, namely

$\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{2l +1}{2}P_l(x)P_l(y) = \delta(x-y) $.
First plug in the integral representation into the right hand side of (6.104) and rewrite the product $\hat{k}\hat{r}$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{2l+1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}\exp(ikr\cos(\theta))P_l(\cos(\theta))P_l(\hat{k}\hat{r})d(\cos(\theta)) = \newline \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{2l+1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}\exp(ikr\cos(\theta))P_l(\cos(\theta))P_l(\cos{(\phi}))d(\cos(\theta)).
\end{align}
Where $\phi$ is the angle between $k$ and $r$.
If you then plug in the completeness property from above, you get the desired result.

Comment: I didn't think about this property. Thanks a lot!